# API data stored in JSON file inside in _next folder is exposed to anyone without any security or Login in Next.JS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

On the protected user Listing page we are using the SSR to hit the api and fetch all user record , then we are rendering it. but if I check On browser(Chrome or firefox) on Network tab , there was one JSON file generated with contain all user data , If I am copy this json file url and send it to any one, they can directly access it as well without any login or any security.

file URL is something like :

> https://******.com/_next/data/1668699485899/dashboard/guests.json

I am using Next.JS with SSR (getServerSideProps), Aslo I am setting Cache-Control on SSR and on next.config.js as well to avoid caching, like that.

on SSR :

```
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
```

on config file :

```
headers: () => [
    {
      source: '/:path*',
      headers: [
        {
          key: 'Cache-Control',
          value: 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
```

How to protect these secure data, and not let other user to access these files directly without login.

Comment: I am returning the data if user is authenticated, but returned data is stored in JSON file inside the _next folder , and this file is directly accessible without login, if you share that file URL to anyone @juliomalves

Answer (score 0):

Passing any data or file through the HTTP request will be visible under the network tab. I suggest you store such data in a database on a sever and then use any server side language of your choice (php, node.js etc) to fetch those data.

[Click for more clarification.](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-hide-JSON-data-from-tools-like-Chrome-development-tools-and-Firebug-etc-as-a-security-beyond-https)